# Linear progress bar that vary according to the value

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying set `animation` on the `linear progress bar` indicator horizontally, which vary according to the value.

But it does not vary according to the value. Below is the code segment:

```
child: LinearProgressIndicator(
  valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.blueAccent),
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  value: remainingDayData,
)
```

Comment: where (and how) do you set `remainingDayData`?

Comment: That is according to an equation. The value of remaingDayData is changing.

Comment: are you using `setState`?

Comment: No I'm not using setState

Comment: thats why your `LinearProgressIndicator` is built only once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get an idea of the context you should show the code where you are showing the progress bar, especially the code that changes the value of remainingDayData.

However, make sure that its value is always between 0 and 1.
Look at this [simple example](https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/flutter-using-linearprogressindicator-examples) with a timer.

Comment: Oh Thank you so much ! I got the point now.